# Is chain mail a notable claim?

Tags: discussion, notability

When checking a claim notability, does the fact the claim was perpetuating via chain mail (or several chain mails) make the claim notable? (Example question: [Is "self-CPR" effective?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/9965/is-self-cpr-effective))

Answer (score 3):

A chain mail should be a fine notable claim...  That said the question here really shows no effort.  Some supporting evidence or ambiguity would make this a better question.  SE is not your typical I have a question please answer it for me site.  You are expected to try to solve the problem yourself and share what you have learned in your question.  Or at the very least find multiple sources of the claim. There is no evidence of that here.

Comment: You shouldn't need to attempt to answer the question yourself, but a bit of effort finding some other sources of notability outside of the chain email would have been nice in this case.

Comment: Well, I have yet to see a chain mail that would survive any effort to check if it is true.

Comment: @Suma - But the point is they are widely believed.

Comment: @jozzas - I guess my point is that Skeptics should not be the first place someone turns to when they get an claim.  Finding evidence that others believe it is a sort of trying to find the answer yourself.